# Save data in map or in the object oriented way as object (class)? (Performace) (General Java)

Tags: java, save, maps

I want to save statistic data from a file in a treemap:

```
public static TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>> playerstats_life = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>();
public static TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>> playerstats_month = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>();
public static TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>> playerstats_week = new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>();
```

(The key is the statistic type like kills, deaths, wins... . In the value is an other treemap with the kill amount and the playername)

I am not very satisfied with this solution, because I have only a limited amount of ram -> performance tuning.

So my question is: Is this a good way, or should i save it in classes/objects?
Like: StatisticGroup -> StatisticEntry?

I apologize for my knowledge, because I am a learning developer.

Btw. I will not store more than 5000-10000 entries.

Thanks four your help.

Comment: Do you need statistics about one or more players?

Comment: Would you provide a sample dataset? Do you really need to store all of the data?

Comment: I will save max 5000-10000 entrys, after that I will use a database instead.